# Display multi dimensional array data in a table

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which outputs this when using var_dump:

```
array(3) { 
    ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "exam_board"
    ["terms"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(7) "pearson" 
    } 
    ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" 
} 
pearsonarray(3) { 
    ["taxonomy"]=> string(9) "exam_code" 
    ["terms"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "a123" 
        [1]=> string(4) "b123" 
        [2]=> string(4) "c123" 
    } 
    ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" 
} 
a123array(3) { 
    ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "exam_level" 
    ["terms"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(15) "pearson-a-level" 
    } 
    ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" 
}
```

The array is defined here:

```
$tax_query = array();

foreach ( get_object_taxonomies( 'exam' ) as $tax ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ $tax ] ) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'terms' => wp_unslash( ( array ) $_POST[ $tax ] ),
            'field' => 'slug',          
        );
    }
}

$args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args['paged'] = $paged;  
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What I'd like to do is loop through the array and output the terms into a table.

The table will need to look like this

```
<tr>
    <td>pearson</td>
    <td>a123</td>
    <td>pearson-a-level</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pearson</td>
    <td>b123</td>
    <td>pearson-a-level</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pearson</td>
    <td>c123</td>
    <td>pearson-a-level</td>
</tr>
```

The loop I have so far returns all of the terms but I don't know how to get them individually, so I can use them in the table.

```
foreach ($tax_query as $key => $value) {           
        var_dump($value);
        echo $value["terms"][0];
    }
```

Comment: post some php code here, where the array is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `$the_query` and `wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'exam_code', array("fields" => "names"));`

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            $the_query->the_post();
            // now $query->post is WP_Post Object, use:
            // $query->post->ID, $query->post->post_title, etc.
            $title = $the_query->post->post_title;
            $id = $the_query->post->ID;
            $exam_date = get_post_meta($the_query->post->ID, 'exam_date', true);
            $exam_code = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'exam_code', array("fields" => "names"));
            if($exam_code) { 
                $exam_code = $exam_code[0]; 
            } else { 
                $exam_code = ""; }
            $exam_time = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'exam_time', array("fields" => "names"));
            if($exam_time) { 
                $exam_time = $exam_time[0]; 
            } else { 
                $exam_time = ""; 
            }


            echo '<tr>'; 
            echo '<td class="tg-yw4l">' . $exam_date . '</td>';
            echo '<td class="tg-yw4l">' . $exam_code . '</td>';
            echo '<td class="tg-yw4l">' . $title . '</td>';
            echo '<td class="tg-yw4l">' . $exam_time . '</td>';
            echo '<tr>';



        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty confusing from your question as to what youre trying to achieve as your data doesnt match your expected output.  But essentially, you need to nest some `foreach` loops in order to iterate over the sub-array.

Something like this.

```
$data = [
    [
        "taxonomy" => "exam_board",
        "terms"    => [
            "pearson",
        ],
        "field"    => "slug",
    ],
    [
        "taxonomy" => "exam_code",
        "terms" => [
            "a123",
            "b123",
            "c123",
        ],
        "field" => "slug",
    ],
    [
        "taxonomy" => "exam_level",
        "terms"    => [
            "pearson-a-level",
        ],
        "field" => "slug",
    ],
];

echo "<table>";
foreach($data as $item) {
    foreach($item['terms'] as $term) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $item['taxonomy'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $term . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

outputs:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>exam_board</td>
        <td>pearson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>exam_code</td>
        <td>a123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>exam_code</td>
        <td>b123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>exam_code</td>
        <td>c123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>exam_level</td>
        <td>pearson-a-level</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5e662ca48e653434f5d05776a8d3bc5cfebaa77)